# Remove HomeAsUpButton arrow from ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have changed the default icon image on my ActionBar and changed it to my own one. I want it to fill the space in the ActionBar completely so that it is right up against the left of the screen and there is no padding around the image.I did this by changing the padding and margins as shown below:

```
    ImageView mLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    mLogo.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    mLogo.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

I have set up my ActionBar like this and removed the arrow as shown below:

```
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        ab.setIcon(R.drawable.bell_logo);
```

The arrow is now gone but the space that it occupied is still there. How can I get rid of this space? Does anyone know what the arrow drawable resource is called so that maybe if I set it to GONE it might work?

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line in your default activity theme:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/an_empty_image</item>
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/an_empty_image</item>
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed to mention the entry for the Android standard AB. It works pretty well in my environment using a 1x1 pixel image and ActionBarSherlock.